# Should I use transients for these API call results?

Tags: cache, api, transient, wp-remote-get

I am consuming an API that gives me a list of people and their profiles. My initial idea was working perfectly fine when it's just the list of people because I was just saving the ids and names using transients and then displaying them on a page. However, I now need to display each person's profile on a page so I reconstructed my idea.

My flow is now like this:

Hit API

Store in cache (transient)

Insert in post (custom post type) - my reason for inserting to the DB is because I need to have a format like /people/person_id. 
/people has the list of people
/people/person_id has a person's profile.

The API consumer just runs once a day.

Is this a good process?

Comment: That's the way I'd do it.

Comment: Hey @vancoder thanks for answering. I'm wondering if there's another way to display people/person_id without inserting to DB and just use transients all the way.

Comment: if you need an index (/people) and a single (/people/person_id) that looks like a CPT to me.